# Deleted Formulas by Google form entries

Tags: arrays, forms, date, if-statement, google-sheets

I've linked a google form to a google sheets, however whenever there is a new submission, formulas in the google sheet are pushed down. Unfortunately, I need these formulas to pull data into a dashboard.

I've tried an arrayforumla (See below) however, doesn't seem like the right fit.

1st column: (A1)
={"Year"; ArrayFormula(Transpose(A2)="Q"&ROUNDUP(month(B2)/3,0))}

2nd column:(B1)
={"Month"; ArrayFormula(Transpose(B2)IF(D2="",,Date(year(D2),month(D2),1)))}

3rd column:(C1)

={"Year"; ArrayFormula(Transpose(C2)="Q"&ROUNDUP(month(B2)/3,0))}

Please see sample google sheet.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fi0SKpuIrUul_wfEkQlTXX5f5e-xYx1ix-gnGgkVds0/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using ArrayFormulas but without arrays. delete everything in C column and use this in C1:

```
={"Year"; ARRAYFORMULA(IF(D3:D="",,YEAR(D3:D)))}
```

Comment: Thank you! That solved it for the month and date columns (solution is in the sample sheet). Any idea on the "quarter" column. I've tried correcting it, just stumped.

Comment: =ArrayFormula("Q"&ROUNDUP(month(E2:E)/3,0)) I believe this is the right formula, would you know by any chance how to have to not have the quarter show in rows that are blank in column D

Comment: Got it! ={"Quarter"; ArrayFormula(IF(D2:D="",,("Q"&ROUNDUP(month(E2:E)/3,0))))}